# Is there a way to obtain a Firebase Auth token using the onCall function in the Cloud Functions emulator?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I'm a beginner in Firebase Functions and I'm trying to get the user's token authenticated by calling the onCall function. I wonder if there is any way to get the token for this function

> Index.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
exports.chat = require("./api/chat")
```

> Chat.js

```
exports.init = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
const key = JSON.parse(data)
console.log(`Starting chat listener to room: ${key}`)

admin.database().ref(`main/${key}/chat`).on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
    chat = snapshot.val()
    //Send obj chat to client
    //admin.messaging().send('test')
  })
})
```

> Client.class

```
chatInit(roomId).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.e("test", ""+task.getResult());
                decodeOnline();
            }
        });

 public Task<String> chatInit(String key) {
    return zFunctions.getHttpsCallable("chat-init")
            .call(key)
            .continueWith(task -> (String) task.getResult().getData());
}
```

Note: I'm performing the tests on Firebase Emulators

Comment: I don't think that Firebase Auth is emulated currently. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1677

Comment: Why does the context parameter return the username and uid, but the token does not? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You might want to edit your question to show more fully what you're doing, including the client code you use to invoke this function and everything you are observing about the function.

Comment: Edited, I hope it is easy to understand

Comment: Not sure, by token do you refer to the Bearer token?